# How to make link open in new tab

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

I know that in posts(answers/questions) I can use html, but when I try to write:

```
<a href="http://some_link" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

its not working, how to fix that?

Answer (score 6):

I do not think this would make the site better. It is irritating if a link opens in a new tab (or window) if you do not want it to. If you want it to open in a new tab you can simply open it in a new tab by choosing that (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left click</kbd> or <kbd>Middle click</kbd>).

See [When should you use target=“_blank” on your links?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/946248/789593) for arguments of why you should not use `target=_blank"`.