# Can we have the meta link in main menu to open in a new tab?

Tags: feature-request

is there any way to make the meta.askubuntu.com link to open in a new tab and not the one already opened with askubuntu.com?

I'm talking about the top menu under Stack exchange. See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: this should help you in the interim ... http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3253/how-to-make-link-open-in-new-tab?rq=1

Comment: @fossfreedom Oh, so we leave it to the user to decide?

Comment: you could add two "poll" answers - one saying "yes please - make this so" ... and the second saying "no thanks - leave it to me" and leave it to the community to vote appropriately.

Comment: Why? Just middle click on the link. Actually, that's how it is now for me. When I click on that link, a new tab is opened. It doesn't work that way for you?

Comment: Seems it would be better left to the user to decide. Closed.

Comment: Hey @fossfreedom just close it down. I don't want to delete it.